VS Code - How to Change the Background Color of the Selected/Opened File Tile in VS Code File Explorer?
In the Explorer sidebar of VS Code, when a file is opened or selected, the background color of its tile changes. I would like to customize this background color for better visibility. Is there a way to modify this specific background color through settings or extensions?
For example, in the image below, I need to change the background tile color of the app.py file when it's selected or opened.


Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be any color customizations in the default settings for the Explorer.

Try this colorCustomization in your settings.json:
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#f00"
}

But it will affect other places where lists are used too.

Yes, I tried this, but it also affects other areas, as you mentioned. Perhaps there is no other property specific to these tiles
